# MSOutlook: Different formatting at different indentation levels

Tags: microsoft-outlook, format

We use MS Outlook quite a lot and I like to follow a particular format when discussiong bugs/problems with other folks. I like to use 2 levels of indentation level in my text. The first (base) level is to put forth my arguments and the next level indentation to provide supporting information.

Often this supporting information is a code snippet or an error message or diagnostic output. It is easier to read the base level text in a font like Lucida Sans Solo and the code snippet in fixed type font. e.g.

Here is a code snippet I would like Alice to review:

```
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("Hello World\n");
    return -1;
}
```

(ok, editor here acts smart and indents stuff itself, but I guess you get the point.)

So the question is: Is there a way for Outlook to automatically choose different format for different indentation level of text that I type/paste?

If there is no automatic way for Outlook to do, is there a quick way for me to choose two styles for the two kinds of text I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no automatics ways to achieve the desired result based on indentation. But you can easily use hotkeys to format selected ranges. Just create necessary text styles on message's **Format Text** tab. After that assign **Shortcut keys** to these styles. Just like in MS Word.